# Read timed out in a WS

Tags: integration

i made an integration Procedure that calls a web Service using an HTTP POST Methode, when i try to  call the web service , the system return the following error :
{
"success": false,
"error": "Read timed out"
}

can you please tell me how i can add the timeOut in the IP ??
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Apex to make these callouts, then you can use the `setTimeout` method [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setTimeout). For example:

```
request.setTimeout(10000);
```

There are however a few transaction limits that are applicable on Apex like

1. Maximum cumulative timeout for all callouts (HTTP requests or Web services calls) in a transaction is 120 seconds.
2. A long-running API request is one that takes over 20 seconds. Salesforce allows only 25 to run at a time in an org.

So if you find yourself hitting those because the external system is taking too long, then consider using [Continuations.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_continuations). Here is an example

```
@AuraEnabled(continuation=true cacheable=true)
public static Object startRequest() {
    Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
    con.continuationMethod='processResponse';

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setEndpoint(LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL);
    con.addHttpRequest(req);
    
    return con;
}

// Callback method
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Object processResponse(List<String> labels, Object state) {
    HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(labels[0]);
    String result = response.getBody();
    return result;
}
```